# React Native - upload to Google Play error: Your app currently targets API level 30 and must target at least API level 31

Tags: react-native, google-play, android-api-levels

I got the following error while upload my app to google:

```
Your app currently targets API level 30 and must target at least API level 31 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 31.
```

Here is my `android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    ...
}
```

How can I upgrade app target API to level 31?

Answer (score 5):

I recently had this warning in my google console.

To solve it, I simply updated the `targetSdkVersion` from 30 to 31 in `android/app/build.gradle` file, which gives the following code (I also had to make sure the `compileSdkVersion` was set to **31**):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31 // You can use 
    //...

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 31
        // ... 
    }
```

And I had to modify the `buildscript` in the `android/app` file as below:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = '30.0.2'
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31 // You can use ``rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion`` instead
        targetSdkVersion = // You can use ``rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion`` instead
        ndkVersion = '21.4.7075529'
        playServicesVersion = '17.0.0' // or find latest version
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = '2.3.0'
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true" ... >
```

Add android:exported="true" or android:exported="false" in AndroidManifest.xml
file.

```html
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    ...
}
```

change compileSdkVersion = 31 and compileSdkVersion = 31 in android/gradle/build.gradle [REACT NATIVE APPS]

Answer (score 1):

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error when I deploy my application on the **Play Store**

so simply update the `targetSdkVersion = 30` to `targetSdkVersion = 31` in `Your_project/android/build.gradle`

```
targetSdkVersion = 31
```

and then run

**cd android**

```
./gradlew clean
```